# Mis imagenes no cargan en GitHub pages al hacer deploy con Angular

Tags: angular, github-pages

Tengo una página la cual ya funciona bien en localhost, todo lo hice en el `app.component.html` y las imágenes se encuentran en una carpeta dentro de assets(carpeta creada al generar el proyecto angular) la estructura es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo subí a github pages con ayuda de `angular-cli-ghpages` con este código `ng deploy --base-href=https://NotAUserName0.github.io/Landing/` que al inicio no funciono hasta que ejecute este otro `ng add angular-cli-ghpages` y solo así se pudo subir, pero las imágenes no cargan, ya intente ponerlas en la carpeta app, pero no sirve incluso sin carpeta.

Dentro del html la forma en la que cargo la imagen es:

```
<img src="../assets/proyect/me.jpg" alt="" class="profile">
```

Alguna otra idea? Me quede ya sin opciones, gracias